# Most efficient way to Select all, and to include a distinct column value - while ordering by date added

Tags: mysql

I have rows that get updated automatically. Sometimes rows are updated (via a new insert - an almost duplicate row) where some columns remain the same - and other columns have new values. I want to pull the most recent up to date row; all the values. Here's what I've got

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT * FROM 
       (SELECT * FROM entries 
                 WHERE dataset_id = xxx 
                 ORDER BY time_added DESC
       ) alias1 GROUP BY title
 ) alias2 ORDER BY timestamp
```

- Work backwards on this list:

  1. SELECT #1 > Reorders these to be displayed based on the timestamp initially created (not added)
  2. SELECT #2 > Filters Select #3 to select distinct title values (most recent title)
  3. SELECT #3 > First query actually executed. Gets the dataset orderd by timestamp added

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I get serious code bad smell from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `group by` and `join`:

```
select e.*
from entries e join
     (select title, max(time_added) as maxta
      from entries e
      where dataset_id = xxx 
      group by title
     ) emax
     on emax.title = e.title and e.time_added = emax.maxta
where dataset_id = xxx
order by e.timestamp;
```

Your method uses a MySQL extension to `group by`, where you have columns in the `select` list that are not in the `group by`.  This is *explicitly* [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) to return indeterminate results.  Don't use features that are documented not to work, even if they seem to under some circumstances.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a unique `time_added` (at least per `title` and `dataset_id`) is necessary to avoid duplicate rows in the output.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I just had to add the title to the join select statement for it to work. `emax.title` wasn't being picked up you see. Thanks!